# Connecting events to socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I cannot solve this issue for the life of me... I need a second pair of eyes to help, please! I am trying to capture the "winner" value within a function that assigns a value to "winner". Then I want to broadcast this data to all of my clients.

here is a link to my repository (to find code: focus on (server) **index.js line 29**, and (client) public/js/general/darkroom/**play.js line 38** and **line 100**) :
https://github.com/omaracrystal/Capstone.Project.io

These are the steps I am taking:

**1)** public/js/general/darkroom/**play.js >line 38**

```
``socket.emit('winner known', winner);``
```

**2)** public/js/general/darkroom/**play.js >line 100**

```
``socket.on('winner known', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  })``
```

**3) index.js >line 29**

```
``socket.on('winner known', function (data) {
      socket.broadcast.emit(data);
  }; ``
```

**What am I doing wrong???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you emit from the socket you need to name your event type. So:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
      var addedUser = false;

      socket.on('winner known', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit(data);
      };
});
```

Should be

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
      var addedUser = false;

      socket.on('winner known', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('winner known', data);
      };
});
```

That way your client side code knows what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

In `index.js` you have used

```
    io.on('connection', function (client) { //line 26
      var addedUser = false;

      socket.on('winner known', function (data) { //socket is undefined
        socket.broadcast.emit(data);
      };
});
```

Instead use

```
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {  //'socket' is the instance of connected client's socket
      var addedUser = false;

      socket.on('winner known', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit(data);
      };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start your node server, have you got any error: something is undefined? If you can start it without any error happen, it's totally make nonsense.